# WPF COMException Crashes Application At Startup (Started Today)

Tags: c#, wpf, crash, .net-4.7

I have just today started seeing this Exception out in the wild on application launch with an app that has been in production for 3 years.

```html
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreatePimcManager()
   at MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateResetEvent(IntPtr& handle)
   at System.Windows.Input.PenThreadWorker..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Input.PenThreadPool.GetPenThreadForPenContextHelper(PenContext penContext)
   at System.Windows.Input.PenThreadPool.GetPenThreadForPenContext(PenContext penContext)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispTabletDeviceCollection.UpdateTabletsImpl()
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispTabletDeviceCollection.UpdateTablets()
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispTabletDeviceCollection..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.get_WispTabletDevices()
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.RegisterHwndForInput(InputManager inputManager, PresentationSource inputSource)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndStylusInputProvider..ctor(HwndSource source)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(HwndSourceParameters parameters)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at APSSSentinel.App.Main()
```

Apparently, some developers using VS2017 who got a Windows update that installed .NET 4.7 have been getting this crash as well, it appears the recommended workaround for now is to turn touch support off.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55303/visual-studio-may-terminate-unexpectedly-when-runn.html

With my application, this is not ideal.  Has anyone else run into this, and found any other sort of workaround?

Comment: Got the same Stack with an application I developed since today. Don't have any clue yet

Comment: https://getsatisfaction.com/quickencommunity/topics/-net-4-7-update

Comment: We're experiencing the same stack on a WPF app on some of our Windows 7 installations but not all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update: Microsoft has now fixed this problem in a [manual update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4033488/comexception-error-from-wpf-applications-after-the-net-framework-4-7-i)** (as noted by Jürgen), *personally I will stick with the workaround until the fix is in the automatic update because it would be a lot of work to make every user install a manual update.*

---

This is obviously a bug in .Net 4.7 that affects Windows 7 and 8/8.1 systems that have a touch input device. Therefore one can hope that Microsoft addresses this in a future update. Meanwhile the only way to retain full functionality is by uninstalling and hiding the update.

Other option is disabling the stylys and touch support either in app.config (like in your link) or in the code if the app is compiled with 4.6 or newer. You didn't specify why that is not ideal but I assume those features are needed? Notice that the disabling doesn't mean that every app is unusable with touch devices, but rather that they only use features that are accessible with a mouse. *Update: Apparently touch device users without a mouse will have trouble using UI that requires scrolling.*

Here's the code examples for those who come here seeking quick fix:

In App.config (works with apps compiled with any framework version)

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.DisableStylusAndTouchSupport=true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

In code (when compiled with .Net Framework >= 4.6)

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.DisableStylusAndTouchSupport", true);
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the app is mostly used on touch devices that may not even have a mouse/keyboard connected, so disabling touch is maybe impossible instead of not ideal.  I do appreciate the suggestion, and would imagine that this would work for most cases.

Comment: Normal actions that can be done with a mouse still work after disabling. So taps on touch devices translate to clicks. I suppose only the advanced functions, like multi-touch and pressure sensitivity, would not work.

Comment: Scrolling in grids and listboxes has given some unpredictable results with this, so I've decided to go the heavy handed route of uninstalling and blocking .NET 4.7 on client machines for now.  I'm in a unique position where I have control over this, for anyone else who does as well, you may want to issue a WUSA uninstall command for the appropriate KB.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/13/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-is-available-on-windows-update-wsus-and-mu-catalog/

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has fixed the issue with .NET 4.7 meanwhile, see
https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/help/4033488/comexception-error-from-wpf-applications-after-the-net-framework-4-7-i

Comment: I found windows update will install it, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/13/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-is-available-on-windows-update-wsus-and-mu-catalog/#comment-367115